# SVG - centering a text node over a circle causing issues in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to center a text node over a circle node using SVG. Here's the example code;

```
    <svg width="200" height="200" style="display:block">
    <g>
        <circle id="number"
                    cx="22"
                    cy="22"
                    r="20"
                    fill="#ffcc66"
                    fill-opacity="1"
                    stroke="#ff9933"
                    stroke-opacity="1"
                    stroke-width="2"
                    stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round">
            </circle>

            <text id="number"
                  x="22"
                  y="22"
                  fill="#333333"
                  font-family="sans-serif"
                  font-size="22px"
                  font-weight="bold"
                  dominant-baseline="middle"
                  alignment-baseline="central"
                  pointer-events="auto"
                  text-anchor="middle">
               7       
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The goal is for the text node to be positioned in the center (horizontally and vertically) over the circle. See http://jsfiddle.net/YpfcJ/ for an example.

It looks good in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera but IE9+ seems to be ignoring the positioning. Anybody know of a solution/reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, SVG support in IE is incomplete and has a lot more bugs that other implementations.

My advice would be to not rely on `alignment-baseline` and instead just adjust the y coordinate of your `<text>` element.  A value of 30 seems to work.